# MVC Unobtrusive validation for a dropdown using knockout.js?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, unobtrusive-validation

I am using knockout.js to populate a dropdown:

```
<select data-bind="options: AvailableUsers, optionsText: 'DisplayName', value: SelectedUser, optionsCaption: '-- Select a User --'" data-val="true" data-val-required="You must select a user." id="SelectedUser" name="SelectedUser"></select>
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="SelectedUser" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

and I am registering the validator to the form and having it called on the submithandler (I dont think this is related to the problem since the validation is executing):

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#UserProfileCreation");
$("#UserProfileCreation").data("validator").settings.submitHandler = mappedModel.save;
```

However when trying to submit the page, it always acts like the dropdown has no selected value. Even when I confirm via console that SelectedUser has a value. I have successfully done the same thing in other pages for textareas like so:

```
<textarea style="width: 100%; height: 50px; min-height: 30px;" name="GroupReply" id="GroupReply" data-bind="value: GroupReply" data-val="true" data-val-required="You must enter a reply."></textarea><br/><span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="GroupReply" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

And that works fine. So I am not sure what I am missing for the dropdown, but whether I select an option or not, it keeps acting like it's blank and bringing up the validation error message. What am I missing?

Comment: I haven't confirmed this, which is why I'm adding as a comment instead of an answer, but I believe that the validation is looking for the value to be set to one of the available options *when validation setup*, i.e. at page load, when there were no available options. By not relying on the data-* validation, and instead applying the rule for that field later (after knockout rendered the options) via JavaScript, I think you will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and it was quite simple due to my lack of understanding of how knockout handles dropdown's selected values.

My `AvailableUsers` in the KO View Model consisted of a list of KeyValueModels which were based off a C# MVC class (converted using the KO mapping plugin):

```
public class KeyValueModel{
   public Guid Id {get; set;}
   public string DisplayName {get; set;}
}
```

I simply needed to add `optionsValue: 'Id'` to the data-bind attribute of the dropdown. However it should be noted that this only works because I am passing a `Guid` as the `SelectedUser` property of the MVC View Model in the action parameter.

There have been times where I wanted to pass an entire javascript object that the dropdown selection represents to the MVC view model, in those cases this solution wouldn't work.

Note in console, if you do NOT have the `optionsValue: 'Id'` you select an option from the dropdown and type `mappedModel.SelectedUser()` you get:

```
Object {Id: "adb9ae2d-01c8-468d-96e6-06ec39039e29", DisplayName: "Johnson, John"}
```

Because knockout can store the whole selected object. HOWEVER, knockout does not set ANY value to the options in the dropdown in the actual HTML markup, they are all null (which is why the validation was failing).

If you do add `optionsValue: 'Id'` and type `mappedModel.SelectedUser()` into console, then you would simply get:

```
"adb9ae2d-01c8-468d-96e6-06ec39039e29"
```

Which for my purposes on this page is fine. As mentioned if you wanted to pass an entire object to the MVC action based on that selection, this setup would not work. You would probably have to do something like setup a hidden field and set it's value to the `SelectedUser().Id` and put the validation on that hidden field.